# Get src content in recaptcha iframe , selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

i did driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")

I am trying to get src in recaptcha iframe. Here is the eleme

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbTo0NDM.&amp;hl=en&amp;v=r20171206132803&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=jsergcmr02x3" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
```

basically I am trying to get the link in src, to extract the captcha key k=...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to extract the captcha key `k=...` from src you can use the following line of code :

```
my_src = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor')]").get_attribute("src")
parts = my_src.split("?k=")
print(parts[1])
```